# Convert IHTMLDOMNode to HTMLAnchorElement

Tags: vb.net

In parseing a web page, the following function works fine when I run it locally:

```
Public Function GetElement(ByVal IHTMLDOMNode As mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode, ByVal InnerText As String) As mshtml.IHTMLElement

    Dim objIHTMLAnchorElement As mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass
    Dim s As String

    s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(IHTMLDOMNode)
    If s = "HTMLAnchorElementClass" Then
        t = GetType(mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass)
        objIHTMLAnchorElement = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(IHTMLDOMNode, t)

        If objIHTMLAnchorElement.innerText.Trim() = InnerText Then
                            Return objIHTMLAnchorElement
        End If
    End if

' code that loks at child nodes and makes a recursive call
```

When it is deployed at the web host provider however, the same input results in the string s being "HTMLAnchorElement" instead of "HTMLAnchorElementClass".

If I change the code to

```
    Dim objIHTMLAnchorElement As mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim s As String

    s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(IHTMLDOMNode)
    If s = "HTMLAnchorElement" Then
        t = GetType(mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement)
        objIHTMLAnchorElement = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(IHTMLDOMNode, t)

        If objIHTMLAnchorElement.innerText.Trim() = InnerText Then
                            Return objIHTMLAnchorElement
        End If
    End if
```

I get an "The type must be __ComObject or be derived from __ComObject" error

What may be the cause of this behavior and/or what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding why (someone please shed light on this), the following works:

```
Dim objIHTMLAnchorElement As mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement
Dim s As String

s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(IHTMLDOMNode)
If s = "HTMLAnchorElement" Then
    t = GetType(mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass)
    objIHTMLAnchorElement = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(IHTMLDOMNode, t)

    If objIHTMLAnchorElement.innerText.Trim() = InnerText Then
                        Return objIHTMLAnchorElement
    End If
End if
```